# How to convert and insert arabic date from datetimepicker into mysql using PHP

Tags: php, datepicker

I have used datetime picker for arabic date. Now I am facing problem in inserting the arabic formatted date into mysql database.

The date (in string) I get is like this "2013-08-10 3:00 في"

When I try to convert into date to insert into database, its not happening.

I have tried temporary solution by using string replace, like:

```
$time = "2013-08-10 3:00 في";
$time = str_replace('في','am',$time);
$start_time = date('Y-m-d H:m:s', strtotime($time));
```

Anyone out there to provide me any alternative solutions.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean a date of the Arabic, not the Gregorian, calendar? Or just a Gregorian date with "am/pm" in Arabic?

Comment: only am/pm in arabic,right now

Comment: Then I'd check to see if the datepicker can be convinced to submit the date using English notation instead of Arabic or the language-neutral 24h format. Failing that, what you have is pretty much the solution.

Comment: thank you. it would be a great help.

Comment: https://github.com/tawfekov/ar-php/blob/master/I18N/Arabic/StrToTime.php

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the following code. Get Arabic.php from the following link 
[Link to Arabic.php](https://github.com/tawfekov/ar-php/blob/master/I18N/Arabic/StrToTime.php)

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); 
$time = time(); 

echo date('l dS F Y h:i:s A', $time); 
echo '<br /><br />'; 

require('I18N/Arabic.php'); 
$Ar = new I18N_Arabic('Date'); 

$fix = $Ar->dateCorrection ($time); 

echo $Ar->date('l dS F Y h:i:s A',  
            $time, $fix); 
echo '<br /><br />'; 

$day = $Ar->date('j', $time, $fix); 
$dir = 'I18N/Arabic/Examples/'; 
echo '<a href="'.$dir.'Moon.php?day='.$day; 
echo '" class="ar_link" target=_blank'; 
echo '>القمر الليلة</a>'; 
echo '<br /><br />'; 

$Ar->setMode(2); 
echo $Ar->date('l dS F Y h:i:s A', $time); 
echo '<br /><br />'; 

$Ar->setMode(3); 
echo $Ar->date('l dS F Y h:i:s A', $time); 
echo '<br /><br />'; 

$Ar->setMode(4); 
echo $Ar->date('l dS F Y h:i:s A', $time); 
echo '<br /><br />'; 

$Ar->setMode(6); 
echo $Ar->date('l dS F Y h:i:s A', $time);
```